# Display all countries that contain at least 2 words in the country name

Tags: sql, oracle

SELECT country_name
FROM Countries
WHERE country_name LIKE '%Word1%' AND country_name LIKE '%Word2%';

Display all countries that contain at least 2 words in the country name. It returns no results but in the system there's United states of America and United kingdom

Comment: But neither `'United states of America'` nor `'United kingdom'` contains the word `'Word1'`. You should rather be looking for a blank in the name.

Comment: Any 2 words or 2 specific words?

Comment: What does Word1 and 2 stand for in your query? “United Kingdom” is not like Word1 so it won’t be returned. You can maybe search for a gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want at least two words, then there is at least one space.  So, if I understand correctly, you want:

```
where country_name like '% %'
```